# Can't add multiple rows with one Insert query in EF asp.net core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

It's repeated question I know and I'm sorry but nothing works.
I need add many rows into one table with foreach statement.

here's my code:

```
foreach (var ques in questions)
{
    await _db.Question.AddAsync(ques);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

add new object for each insertion

```
foreach (var ques in questions)
{
    Question temp = new Question();
    temp.QuestionText = ques.QuestionText;
    temp.TypeId = ques.TypeId;
    await _db.Question.AddAsync(temp);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

AddRange

```
List<Question> result = new List<Question>();
foreach (var ques in questions)
{
    Question temp = new Question();
    temp.QuestionText = ques.QuestionText;
    temp.TypeId = ques.TypeId;
    result.Add(temp);
}
_db.Question.AddRange(result);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

I also tried without Async and tried to add the id manually but nothing work.
the ID for sure is AutoIncremental.

EDit:
the question Class:

```
    public partial class Question
    {
        public int IdQuestions { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public int? TypeId { get; set; }
        public int? QuestionairId { get; set; }

        public virtual Questionnaire Questionair { get; set; }
        public virtual Questiontype Type { get; set; }
    }
```

the json:

```
[
{
    "QuestionText": "How you doin'??",
    "TypeId": 1,
    "QuestionairId": 1
},
{
    "QuestionText": "Whaaaaaaaat??",
    "TypeId": 1,
    "QuestionairId": 1
}
]
```

Comment: *Why* isn't it working? What's going wrong, is it throwing an exception, not updating the database, or something else?

Comment: Just the first row is added correctly then returns bad Request no exception is thrown.

Comment: That's weird. Could you [edit] your question to include the class definition for `Question` as well as a minimal example of the JSON that you're posting to the server which results in this bad request?

Comment: If there's a "bad request' so exception is thrown for sure. Chceck your logs.

Comment: Did you check that your JSON gets properly converted into your objects? Also, are your Entity Framework configurations correct (i.e foreign key mapping)?

Comment: thanks very much, there was an error with Entity Framework configurations even I revised it many times before. @MindSwipe